# Getting error sudo: pam_authenticate: Module is unknown

Tags: pam

I am new to Ubuntu and have installed Ubuntu 12.04.3 on my laptop. I need to install VAS on it but when I do I get the error:

```
sudo: pam_authenticate: Module is unknown.
```

And I cannot make any other changes. Anything that requires `sudo` I get this error. Also you cannot logon remotely to the box.
These are the packages installed for PAM. Can you tell me what module I am missing??

```
#dpkg --get-selections | grep -i pam
libpam-modules                                  install
libpam-modules-bin                              install
libpam-runtime                                  install
libpam0g                                        install
python-pam                                      install
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
sudo pam-auth-update --force
```

to update pam configuration. If it works well and good otherwise possibly you dont have all the needed modules installed..

Comment: your solution needs sudo, and it is previously said sudo is not working anymore.